# CSS Drop down menu on mobile. how to get around :hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I've had a search and I couldn't find anything & also it's my first time using the site so hope it hasn't been asked.

I've run into a situation. I'm by no means an experienced website maker. I'm learning as I go. I have a CSS drop down menu that works fine on desktop browsers. When I get into the realm of mobile I encounter a problem, namely that `:hover`doesn't work (obviously).

I found this : http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly but I can't get the ruddy thing to work.

The page in question I'm applying it to is here : http://www.inkslinger.co.uk/calibre/index.html I really can't work this out and its driving me absolutely batty. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found an easy workaround which I have used here
 [hover example](http://new.calmbeginnings.co.uk/)

The Post Natal and Ante Natal options, when hovered over, trigger the drop down, but you may notice that they are NOT links themselves. In my original model they were links, but when I realised this would not work on touch devices, I simply made them into triggers for the drop down boxes, and put the links inside the boxes too. So for you, your 'What we do' link, would not be a link, just a trigger for the dropdown menu, and then in the menu you can have your link to the 'what we do' info.

It is also worth remembering that certain touch devices, such as some iPads, do not like hover states at all, if you find that the hover state won't trigger your dropdown menu, then add 'onclick="return true"' to the list item in question. This will usually make the hover state work like a click.

Hope this helps, what I've written represents about 3 days of poring over my library of reference books.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem and changed the hover to clicks.

Comment: The problem i have is that one of my hover menu items, the top link is a link to another page as well. so I'm thinking the click won't work ?

Comment: @ikillbears In the "new" responsive/adaptive web, we have to make compromises. If the top level menu item is a link, you need to consider changing that.

Comment: You can switch your menu from the hover to desktop version and using the clicks for the touch devices. The environment is different the hover doesn't exist in touch devices.

You can use media query for the detection and switch the css or content.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using hover, which is of course impossible on touch devices, using :active would likely be a good start. Selection something is still possible on touch devices, bind the menu to the active state of a toggle and you're done.

Comment: I've given that a go where i think it would work but doesn't seem to solve the issue. The first link I posted contains what seems to be a solution judging by the video on the website. However, I can't for the life of me get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You will have to switch from hover to click event for this case. There's no workaround for that.

You should definitely consider changing your design to have a hamburger styled menu which opens from left for touch devices.

See this demo from the link that you posted. It changes to a different menu style when you open it in mobile device.
http://osvaldas.info/examples/drop-down-navigation-touch-friendly-and-responsive/

Also if you want to have your top link as a direct link to other page; you can have two separate clicks on the top button for that. First click will open the menu and after the menu is opened you can assign the direct link to it as done in the above demo.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line of code inside your head tag like this:

```
<head>
  <script>document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){}, true);</script>
</head>
```

Create for your hover element an active class like this:

```
element:hover, element:active { Your CSS }
```

Voila.